# If $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ in real numbers, does the function $f$ have to be continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, algebraic-topology

Given $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, and the function $f$ satisfies $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for any $x,y\in S$. Can we say that this function $f$ must be continuous?

I think it is false, but couldn't give an example. Can someone tell me whether it is true or not? Thank you very much.

Comment: No.consider Micah's link.on the other hand assuming continuity, it must be exponential

Comment: @Brian: You're absolutely right. You should have the dupe hammer powers to reopen and reclose. And you should do that.

Comment: @Asaf: I didn’t realize that the hammer extended to reopening; thanks!

Comment: The answer may be a matter of opinion! If you take the AXiom of Choice to be true, the answer is that $f$ need not be continuous. If you take the Axiom of Determinacy to be true, the answer is that $f$ must be continuous.